# Android password protect sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an android application in wich I can export/inport my database to sdcard.

I do it simply by using:

```
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
```

What I would like to do is to password protect my exported database so if anyone tries to open it using sqlite browsing programms they would need to enter a password.

Can this be done(and how)?

Comment: I don't think you can password protect a sqlite database but what you can do is encrypt the data using a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of protect database, you could encrypt file (exported database) there's some threads talking about this:

[How to encrypt and decrypt file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android)

[Encrypting files with AES on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115035/encrypting-files-with-aes-on-android)

**UPDATE1:**

To decrypt file on desktop, there's this thread:

[Decrypting data on desktop that was encrypted on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406368/decrypting-data-on-desktop-that-was-encrypted-on-android)

Comment: @TadejVengust, is it useful ?

Comment: Yes thank you, but no where does it say how I can then decrypt the file on my computer not on android. :(

Comment: So if I want to password protect my database I have to encrypt my whole file when exporting and then decrpyt it on my computer with a program I write in java? There is no easyer way? because I will export and import very frequently and this will consume quite some time.

Comment: @TadejVengust You're right regarding the process to encrypt/decrypt. There's some commercial libraries to help you to do it as https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ . Regarding time to encrypt/decrypt you're right it take lot of time. You could use an hardware crypto processor to increase speed.